# how to call a phone number through javascript without using <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I designed a mobile web page. There I have a phone number field, which on clicking should call that particular number. I can't use:

```html
<a href="tel:+1800229933"></a>
```

Because I have added the phone number field using table tag as follows:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Phone: 900 300 400</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Are there any other methods(like OnClick event) to call that phone number on clicking that column?

Comment: What is the reason you cannot add the `a` tag to the table cell??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Phone: 900 300 400</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

to:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="tel:+900300400">Phone: 900 300 400</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yeah.it's working now. i think previuosly i have added <a> tag wrongly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, you solve the problem, but it is not the direct answer to the **Without Using `<a>` tag**. I'm seeking to find a better solution. because I need it on a ReactJS stack.

Comment: Isn't is question specifically asks without `a` tag?

Answer (score 118):

You can simply add an `onclick` handler to your `<tr>` tag, then call `window.open("tel:+1800229933");`.

Like so:

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="window.open('tel:900300400');">
    <td>Phone: 900 300 400</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer as this is an implementation done without the <a /> anchor tag as asked in the question.

Comment: Strange, But working fine for first time, another time navigating me to blank window. Dont know what's the reason, any idea?

Comment: @PardeepJain Probably best to open a new question with a minimal example.

Comment: I know this question is long time ago, but for navigating to a new tab issue, just make it open in current tab: `window.open('tel:123123123', '_self');`. For more options, read this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 18):

Find the cell content with jQuery, replace the "Phone:" part and make it a link. The selection of the cell with a class is one way of doing it. Another would be to select in the real table the cell with a code similar to "the second cell in each row of the table".
Here a working example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('.phonecell').click(function() {
          var PhoneNumber = $(this).text();
          PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.replace('Phone:', '');
          window.location.href = 'tel://' + PhoneNumber;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="phonecall">Phone: 900 300 400</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its better because uses JS without new tab

Answer (score 8):

The certain answer for the title of the question, hence, **without using `<a>` tag** is to make a helper function to simulate the action of `<a href="tel:`:

```js
const simulateCall = phoneNumber => window.open(`tel:${phoneNumber}`, '_self');
```

The *target* `_self` causes we have an exact look like call simulation just like clicking `<a href="tel:`.

Now the `simulateCall` helper function can be used anywhere. like my case:

```js
const callHandler = phoneNumber => () => {
  // I want to do something here then make a call
  simulateCall(phoneNumber);
};

~~~

<SomeComponent onClick={callHandler} ...
```

Comment: `_self` for target is the key. Otherwise it's going to open a new window.

Answer (score 3):

Shorted answer

this will keep you in the same window

```
window.location = "tel:495898694"
```

while this will open another tab and then call the number

```
window.open('tel:900300400');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be you'll find it helpful
https://www.theharnishes.com/phone.html

Answer (score 0):

**If you need to open the dialer of mobile phone when clicking on a button, you can try this:**

```
            onClickBtn={() => window.open(`tel:+919876543210`)}
```

example:

```
           <ActionButton
            onClickBtn={() => window.open(`tel:+919876543210`)}
            title="Call Owner"
            icon={<LeftCircleTwoTone />}
          />
```