# create link from html input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, concatenation

I want to know if it is possible to generate a link (`<a href = "tel :`) from html inputs. I explain myself;

I have 3 html text inputs and those 3 inputs must be concatenated to result in telephone dialing. Example

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xouny.png)

In simple words I need that the result be a `<a href = "tel :` so I can click and redirect to a softphone

Thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share some code? You can get the `value` of each input and concatenate them.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try and research?

Comment: Thanks , you can see my project here http://naughty-newton-d6d67c.netlify.com/ I need that the fields INX,PREFIX, and Number be concatenated, and shows the result in "Dialing" fields as href tel. 
But I can't figure out how make it :c  (noob)

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to implement this.

Here is a similar article and you can find out the preferable answer there.

[how to call a phone number through javascript without using  tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897213/how-to-call-a-phone-number-through-javascript-without-using-a-tag)