# How to add a link on a toogle button on second text

Tags: html, url, button

I need a link on the text ”[[phone]]” Which appears the first time you press the button. The link should be ”tel:[[phone]]” to be able to click on a phone number and call it directly.

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById("myButton1").value = "[[phone]]";
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input onclick="change()" type="button" class="button" value="Visa nummer" id="myButton1">
```

Comment: where's the value of `[[phone]]` coming from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to call a phone number through javascript without using <a> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897213/how-to-call-a-phone-number-through-javascript-without-using-a-tag)

Comment: Yea maybe, do u think without using <a> hide crewling bots?

Comment: You will not be able to hide the number from bots w/ the solutions you are seeking. Event hiding the button (or `<a>` tag) does nothing to prevent the phone number to be added from somewhere else in the code.  More advanced bots will be able to harvest it even after you've clicked on the button or tag.

Comment: Ah okey! Thank you for the Quick help

Comment: These are some options (to prevent showing the number) but I am not sure they address your use case (to make a call if the button is clicked) https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26339

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) in your click() -function, that way you can use any element.
'_self' is so it opens the link in the same window.

```
window.open('tel:123456789', '_self');
```

Similar question: [how to call a phone number through javascript without using <a> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897213/how-to-call-a-phone-number-through-javascript-without-using-a-tag)

Comment: If it is only similar please explain the relevant difference.

Comment: Hey, thx for the help. But I am figure it out where to place it. Becouse i need the oneclick=”change()” to be able to click on the button to change text. How to add this code on the secound text?

Comment: Please show your code and specify the second text