# the href "tel:" and "mailto:" are not clickable on Google Search app (iOS) on website

Tags: href, tel, google-ios-vision

I use the `<a href="tel:+6421212121"> Call Button </a>` on a website. The link is clickable and works as expected on Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Edge ios apps. However, when browsing the website using the Google Search App on iOS the links do nothing when clicked. Is there a way to make them work as expected?

To know what I am talking about open any website with a phone number, click the phone number in a browser and also browse on Google Search App.

Here are some websites of tradies that contain phone numbers: Scroll down to footer to see the phone numbers:

```
https://housepainterauckland.co.nz/
https://www.thehousepainters.co.nz/
https://superiorpainters.co.nz/
```

Update: have tried this but no luck: [how to call a phone number through javascript without using <a> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897213/how-to-call-a-phone-number-through-javascript-without-using-a-tag) same thing, works on browsers but doesn't work when browsing through Google Search app.

Comment: You have an error in your tag syntax (a colon where you should have an equals sign). I am shocked that it works in any browser.

Comment: that was not a copy and paste, my bad. I have checked it is fine on the website.